# Extraction of Data from an RS-485 enabled Multi Function Meter Using Raspberry Pi-3. Have used the following code but it throws an error?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, uart, modbus, serial-communication

**Have used the following code to extract data from Rs-485 enabled multifunction meter using Raspberry Pi-3**

**The Multifunction meter used is L&T WL4440.**

```
NOTE-- Register addresses are offset from 40001 so inputting register 0 in the code is            actually 40001, 3 = 40004 etc...
Arguments - (register start address, number of registers to read, function code)


import minimalmodbus
mb_address = 1
modbus_read = minimalmodbus.Instrument('/dev/ttyUSB0',mb_address)
modbus_read.serial.baudrate = 38400
modbus_read.serial.bytesize = 8
modbus_read.serial.parity = minimalmodbus.serial.PARITY_NONE
modbus_read.serial.stopbits = 1
modbus_read.serial.timeout = 0.5
modbus_read.mode = minimalmodbus.MODE_RTU
modbus_read.clear_buffers_before_each_transaction = True
modbus_read.close_port_after_each_call = True
print("")
print("Requesting Data ...")
data =modbus_read.read_registers(148, 1, 3)
print("")
print("The totalcurrent is",data)
modbus_read.serial.close()
```

**THE ERROR IS displayed below and  the image attached:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sanjeevi/Modbus_read/modbus_read.py", line 37, in <module>
    data =modbus_read.read_registers(148, 1, 3)
  File "/home/sanjeevi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/minimalmodbus.py", line 927, in read_registers
    returnvalue = self._generic_command(
  File "/home/sanjeevi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/minimalmodbus.py", line 1276, in _generic_command
    payload_from_slave = self._perform_command(functioncode, payload_to_slave)
  File "/home/sanjeevi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/minimalmodbus.py", line 1359, in _perform_command
    payload_from_slave = _extract_payload(
  File "/home/sanjeevi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/minimalmodbus.py", line 1918, in _extract_payload
    _check_response_slaveerrorcode(response)
  File "/home/sanjeevi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/minimalmodbus.py", line 3584, in _check_response_slaveerrorcode
    raise error
minimalmodbus.IllegalRequestError: Slave reported illegal data value
```

[image: screenshot shoring image]

Comment: `IllegalRequestError` indicates that the slave (i.e. your meter) has rejected the request. This means we cannot answer without more information (i.e. Make/Model of the meter, and, ideally, a link to it's Modbus documentation). Using [debug mode](https://minimalmodbus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/debugmode.html#debugmode) will provide more info too (i.e. the specific error). I'd guess that you probably need function code `4`).

Comment: Ref the edit - Please try `modbus_read.read_registers(148, 2, 3)`. The field is a float stored over two registers, it's common for devices setup like this to refuse requests that don't include the whole value (i.e. two registers). If that does not work add 1 to the register #. Note that it's often easier to test access with a tool like [mbpoll](https://github.com/epsilonrt/mbpoll).

Comment: Could you use something like wireshark usb or usbtrace to see what is being returned?

Comment: @cup the response is exception code 3 (ILLEGAL DATA VALUE); this is visible in the screenshot.

Comment: It tells us it is an illegal data value but not what the value is.  Sometimes the value helps - eg if we are sending 55 and getting 33, then the baud rate could be out by a factor of two.

Comment: @cup possible but very unlikely due to the CRC built into the protocol.

Comment: @cup i have tried by adjusting baud rate but when i change baud rate it returns that no communication is built